# Как правильно реализовать API?

Tags: php, android, json, api

Здравствуйте.

Есть сайт(сервис) по предоставлению услуг, внутри сайта есть личный кабинет пользователя, с его историей заказов, статусами заказов, историей оплаты и т.д.

Необходимо сделать API, которым бы пользовалось android приложение.

Как я начал делать, при авторизации с приложения делаю запрос к API такого плана:
`/api/?user.checkAuth={"login":"admin", "pass":"md5('.....)"}` проверяю правильный ли хеш.

А дальше генерирую случайную строку и сохраняю ее на сервере в паре СТРОКА - ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ, так же отсылаю ее в ответ приложению, те эдакий сессионный токен, который знаю я, и знает приложение.

Далее приложение запрашивает список заказов, передавая мне только то, что знает, те токен, который я выдал при авторизации.
Запрос на список заказов:

```
/api/?user.getUserOrders={"token":"29db74ae5302f6fafa75428ada7f1871"}
```

на стороне сервера я принимаю токен, смотрю есть ли такой токен вообще к какому пользователю он привязан, и если все окей, то возвращаю JSON с заказами.

Тут первый вопрос, я двигаюсь в правильном направлении? и вытекающая проблема из текущей реализации:

1. есть у пользователя телефон и планшет с приложением;
2. он авторизовался на телефоне - получил токен - пользуется;
3. заходит с планшета - получает токен, КОТОРЫЙ ПЕРЕЗАПИСЫВАЕТСЯ если уже привязан к какому-то пользователю - пользуется.

Вот тут и проблема, теперь если пользователь зайдет со своего телефона в приложение и попытается что-то запросить, передав токен с который сохранен в телефоне, то этот токен мы уже не найдем (т.к. перезаписали пару пользователь-токен при авторизации с планшета) и соответственно кинем его на страницу авторизации, для получения токена... и так до бесконечности, пользователь может работать только с 1ого устройста...

Как решить эту проблему, те сохранить безопасность, работая с токенами, и дать пользователю возможность иметь несколько токенов?

Чем-то грозит реализация, такая, что один `user_id` может иметь несколько токенов?

Как организовать сброс этих токенов и нужен ли он?

Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов (а вообще, тема холиварная):

1. При первом запуске приложения, оно запрашивает у сервера токен устройства.
2. Привязка на сервере осуществляется по 3-м параметрам: токен устройства, токен сессии, пользователь

Никакой угрозы в хранении нескольких токенов для одного пользователя нет. Единственно, что вам необходимо изучить best practics по использованию сессий. Например как это рекомендовано в [PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.session.security.management.php)

**UPD** А зачем вы передаете в URI готовый JSON, какой в том смысл?

Сравните:

```
/api/?user.getUserOrders={"token":"29db74ae5302f6fafa75428ada7f1871"}

/api/?method=getUserOrders&token=29db74ae5302f6fafa75428ada7f1871
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите https://jwt.io/.

Из преимуществ:

- Стандарт
- Не нужны сессии.
- Поддержка разными языками(одинаковая) одновеременно (можете писать части приложения на разных языках).
- Можно перенести проверку на уровень сервера.
  https://github.com/auth0/nginx-jwt

Недостатки:

- Нельзя удалить/запретить токен. Токен становится недействительным только когда "истекает срок годности".

Если не связываться с JWT перенесите токен авторизации в заголовки запроса.

`Authorization: 29db74ae5302f6fafa75428ada7f1871`